# How to Expand one content view while the other content view is with fixed height in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

[image]I have two content views one after the other, were one view is with fixed height and the other view should fill and expand the parent view.
I have tried the following things :

Using 2 content view inside a StackLayout, with vertical options as "End".

```
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="End" Spacing="0" >
   <ContentView  x:Name="red_ContentView" BackgroundColor="Red" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        </ContentView>
        <ContentView x:Name="blue_ContentView" BackgroundColor="Blue" HeightRequest="66">
        </ContentView>
</StackLayout>
```

I want the white space in the image to be filled with red_ContentView.

Comment: Have you tried VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" on the StackLayout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noted above, using VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" on the StackLayout might get you what you want.

An alternative is to use Grid instead of StackLayout, something like this:

```
<Grid VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
      <RowDefinition Height="66"/>
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>

   <ContentView  x:Name="red_ContentView" BackgroundColor="Red" Grid.Row="0">
   </ContentView>

   <ContentView x:Name="blue_ContentView" BackgroundColor="Blue" Grid.Row="1">
   </ContentView>
</Grid>
```